# C struct aligned

Tags: c, struct, alignment

Is there some gcc portable pragma, so I can do C struct *not* to be memory aligned?

I want my program to be portable (Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS, Cygwin), but I will stay with gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to align members of a structure (that is not have any padding between members), with `gcc` you can use `packed` attribute:

```
struct bla
{
    int x;
    char y;
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

or use `pack` `pragma`:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct bla
{
     int x;
     char y;
};
#pragma pack()
```

or compile using `-fpack-struct` option.

You can also force a minimum alignment for the whole structure with `aligned` attribute, but as far as I know you cannot disable the alignment of the whole structure with `gcc`.

Comment: Works on Linux GCC over ARM CPU :)
any idea if this is portable beyond gcc ?

Comment: @Nick attributes or pragmas are compiler extensions and are implementation dependent. Most compilers have such extensions but they vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: Sure. this is why I do not look for compatibility beyond gcc

Comment: I am tempted to paste this too:
https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/does-packed-struct-hurt-performance-on-x86_64/